# Unpack an EAR file using maven

Tags: maven, ear

I have an EAR file from some build. I want to extract the contents of this EAR file into another folder. I am confused how to do this. I have looked and tried 
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/
and
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html

but either maven is unable to find the file or it has dependency issues.

Since I am new to maven I don not understand how to set these plugins up.

I got the following error on using the below plugin.

*Failure to find ECM:ECM:ear:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository*

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>ECM</groupId>
                                <artifactId>ECM</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0</version>
                                <type>ear</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/earoutput</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I tired the ant plugin in maven and it works. But I am not sure if it the best way to do it.

Comment: What are the repositories your Maven is configured to look up? Where does the other build (from which you took the EAR file) deploy the artifact (EAR)? If they are not same repositories, you might want to configure the other repository in the settings.xml. Or just copy the artifact structure to your local Maven repository.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `dependency:unpack-dependencies`. I just modify my answer because according to your comments, your ear is generated by some other build. If you do not have an Enterprise repository that you can deploy your ear artifact, you have to use "system" scope, but please note that it is usually **discouraged**.

Add below dependency to your pom.xml

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>ECM</groupId>
>     <artifactId>ECM</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0</version>
>     <type>ear</type>
>     <scope>system</scope>
>     <systemPath>/path/to/your/abc.ear</systemPath>
> </dependency>
> ```

Add the below plugin to your postBuild module pom.xml

> ```
>  <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>2.6</version>
>     <executions>
>         <execution>
>             <id>unpack</id>
>             <phase>package</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
>             </goals>
>             <configuration>
>                 <includeArtifactIds>ECM</includeArtifactIds>
>                 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/earoutput</outputDirectory>
>             </configuration>
>         </execution>
>     </executions>
>  </plugin>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and its [unpack](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) goal can do this.

Sample configuration:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.6</version>
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <id>unpack</id>
     <phase>package</phase>
     <goals>
       <goal>unpack</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
       <artifactItems>
         <artifactItem>
           <groupId>myear</groupId>
           <artifactId>myear</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
           <type>ear</type>
         </artifactItem>
       </artifactItems>
       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/earoutput</outputDirectory>
     </configuration>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

This takes the 'myear.ear' artifact and extracts it to the 'target/earoutput' directory.  This also works with JARs, WARs and any other zip-like file.  The phase this executes under is 'package' - this may be too late if you need to use these resources in other parts of the build.  Change the phase to something earlier such as 'generate-resources' if needed.

You mentioned that you already tried using the dependency plugin.   Is the EAR file from another Maven project, and has it been installed in the local Maven repository?  If it still doesn't work post the plugin configuration you tried to use.

---

(edit: update information on dependencies and local repository)

For this to work, your EAR file needs to be put into your local Maven repository (this is just a directory on your disk).  But if other people need to build your project as well, you have a few options:

- import the EAR into your local repository, and also deploy to a remote repository so everyone can get it (recommended, but requires you to set up a corporate Maven repository)
- give the EAR to everyone and have them put it into their local repository using a couple of Maven commands (might be OK for a few developers, less overhead than setting up a whole repository server)
- check the dependent EAR into source control under your project and unpack it (not the recommended way of doing things) in a goal in your project

---

Importing into your local repository is easy.  It's very similar to [these instructions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Use the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-EAR-file-on-local-filesystem> -DgroupId=myear
-DartifactId=myear -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=ear
```

(modify path, groupId, artifactId and version as needed)

Group ID and artifact ID are there simply to uniquely identify artifacts.

Once you install this in the local repository, the dependency plugin should work and find the artifact.

Comment: I do not understand what groupId, artifactId and version tags mean. My EAR file is from some build which I have downloaded from somewhere and want to extract the contents. It is not related to this maven project.

Comment: @SairamSankaran added some info on installing EAR into the local repository

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this example of Maven EAR plugin for Unpacking a module](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/unpacking-a-module.html) yet?

Comment: Yes. I am not sure what to specify for groupId. I left it as is and got the error as Artifact[sar:artifactGroupId:ECM] is not a dependency of the project

Comment: This assumes that your EAR file exists as an artifact inside the Maven  repository.

Comment: OK. How can I specify the exact location of the EAR file?

Comment: You just need to specify the correct `artifactId` and `groupId` in the module section. The artifact should exist in whatever repository Maven is configured with. Also, I'm not sure what a `sarModule` is. Have you tried with `earModule`?